# Flip a SwiftUI Shape based on layout direction

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, localization

I've made a SemiRoundedRectangle shape which I'm using to clipShape a side menu. I need to flip it if the user is in an RTL language, but not sure the best way of achieving this.

I've tried `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)` but this flips the actual Arabic text too. When I try rotating the shape it no longer conforms to the Shape protocol and so I can no longer use it in `.clipShape`. Everything else in SwiftUI just magically flips itself when I switch into Arabic, is there something I could add to my shape to give it these magic powers too?

Thanks for your help :)

```
import SwiftUI

struct SemiRoundedRectangle: Shape {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX+cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: rect.height - cornerRadius),
                    radius: cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: .degrees(90),
                    endAngle: .degrees(180), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius),
                    radius: cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: .degrees(180),
                    endAngle: .degrees(270), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        
        return path
    }

}

struct TestView {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("ايه الأخبار؟")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.green)
            .clipShape(SemiRoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0))
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try attaching the `clipShape` to the `Color.green` instead:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("ايه الأخبار؟")
            .padding()
            .background(
                Color.green /// here!
                    .clipShape(SemiRoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0))
                    .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
            )
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

| English | RTL Language |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Green rectangle with left corners rounded, at screen left] | [image: Green rectangle with right corners rounded, at screen right] |

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic solution:

```
extension Shape {
    func flipped(_ axis: Axis = .horizontal, anchor: UnitPoint = .center) -> ScaledShape<Self> {
        switch axis {
        case .horizontal:
            return scale(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: anchor)
        case .vertical:
            return scale(x: 1, y: -1, anchor: anchor)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Use for this case:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("ايه الأخبار؟")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .clipShape(SemiRoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0).flipped())
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 17+

Starting with Xcode 15, `Shape` has a `layoutDirectionBehavior` property that allows it to support flipping the shape horizontally automatically.

If deploying to iOS17 (& equivalents), this property defaults to `.mirrors` – so the shape will flip automatically. If deploying to earlier, it defaults to `.fixed` (for compatibility, I'm guessing).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/layoutdirectionbehavior-361s6